# Get plates from Hikvision LPR camera (returning only the last 20 plates) How to retrieve more?

Tags: xml, isapi, lpr, hikvision

I want to retrieving plates from LPR Hikvision camera but xml file returns only last 20 plates. Someone can help me to define correctly xml parameters to retrieve more registries?

POST URL:   .../ISAPI/Traffic/channels/1/vehicleDetect/plates

POST XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AfterTime version="2.0" xmlns="http://www.hikvision.com/ver20/XMLSchema">
    <picTime>2020-06-10T00:00:00Z</picTime>
</AfterTime>
```

XML return this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <Plates version="2.0" xmlns="http://www.hikvision.com/ver20/XMLSchema">

   <Plate>
     <captureTime>20200510...</captureTime>
     <plateNumber>xxxxxxx</plateNumber>
     <picName>20200510...</picName>
     <country>xxx</country>
     <laneNo>1</laneNo>
     <direction>forward</direction>
     <matchingResult>otherlist</matchingResult>
  </Plate>

  ... + 19 ...

</Plates>
```

Answer (score 1):

URL is `ISAPI/ContentMgmt/search`

POST argument format is

```
<?xml version: '1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
        <CMSearchDescription>
            <searchID>ANY_STRING_HERE</searchID><trackIDList><trackID>103</trackID></trackIDList>
            <timeSpanList><timeSpan><startTime>2020-06-22T02:25:13Z</startTime><endTime>2021-06-22T02:25:13Z</endTime></timeSpan></timeSpanList>
            <contentTypeList><contentType>metadata</contentType></contentTypeList>
            <maxResults>100</maxResults><searchResultPostion>0</searchResultPostion>
            <metadataList>
                <metadataDescriptor>//recordType.meta.std-cgi.com/vehicleDetection</metadataDescriptor>
                <SearchProperity><plateSearchMask/><nation>255</nation></SearchProperity>
            </metadataList>
        </CMSearchDescription>
```

`trackID` argument may be different for your camera